# Configuration of Hudson in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hudson

I have a eclipse Dynamic web project  java base and use maven for creating project .But i want to build  the project in Hudson for testing purpose .

So please anyone can give me steps to configure Hudson  for building project in eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Please post on any specific error. You can ask the same question to Google -> Hudson + configuration

Comment: @VinayVeluri Actually i have no idea about Hudson  I also tryed in google for this http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/how-to-set-up-continuous-integration-with-eclipse-selenium-webdriver-maven-and-hudson

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch03.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) Read a guide about Hudson an CI.

1) Create a new taks on hudson based on maven project.

2) Configure the task to checkout the code from your svn/git.

3) Configure the mvn step to execute "mvn test".

4) Check your results.